# How SVG is drawn in HTML

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

Good day,

I was playing around with SVG, when I noticed this behaviour.

Background: I was loading the SVG using snap.svg. The node I wanted to replace was inside a group <g> node.

I selected an SVG node using document.getElementById. Then I got the parent. Then I replaced the textContent property of the parent with another set of SVG text. However, the new SVG was not visible.

I opened the developer tools in google chrome. I selected the same node in the node tree view. I edited the node as HTML, replacing all SVG nodes with the new SVG text. However, the new SVG was not visible.

Lastly, I selected the root element, the SVG tag itself. Then edited the SVG tag as HTML, appending the SVG text as the last child element. Now the new SVG was visible?

Are there SVG drawing rules that I should be aware of? I've read in other questions that it's hard/impossible to replace SVG text the save way HTML can be replaced by using node.innerHTML.

Comment: Just wondering, if you were using Snap to load the SVG, why not use Snap to manipulate the SVG as well ?

Comment: Snap is good if you're manipulating the SVG programatically. However, the SVG I wanted to add is in a string. I haven't seen a method of Snap that can read a string and turn it into a whole tree of nodes and stuff.

Comment: How about the parse method of Snap, so http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Snap.parse then you just append it to whatever other svg you want. Here is an example using it to add a title http://svg.dabbles.info/snaptut-title.html . I suspect if you have a specific example, it may be possible to come up with a more specific answer that suits.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at using [Element.innerSVG](http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Element.innerSVG) which is provided by Snap.svg?

Also, `Element.innerHTML` should work on svg elements too, and it already does work in some browsers (e.g newer versions of Opera and Chrome, see [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=311080)). This is defined in the [DOM Parsing spec](http://domparsing.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-element-innerhtml).

Answer (score 0):

You should try creating the SVG elements with the namespace aware `createElementNS` API. For an example, see http://www.kevlindev.com/tutorials/basics/shapes/js_dom/